# Password Protecting MS Excel 97-2003 Version using win32

Tags: python, win32com

I have imported win32com.client as 32 for getting MS Excel 97-2003 (.xls) version password protected using python program. However, this version is unable to get password protected. Below is the complete code:

```
import win32com.client as win32
def password_protect_excel(file_path, password, filename):
    global total_excel_protected

    print(f"Setting Password for - '{filename}'")

    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    excel.DisplayAlerts = False

    try:
        workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_path, False, False, None, password)
        workbook.Password = password
        workbook.Save()
        workbook.Close()
        excel.Quit()

        print("Renaming the Excel File ")
        # Rename the file with the "_protected" suffix
        base_name, extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)
        new_file_path = base_name + "_protected" + extension
        os.rename(file_path, new_file_path)

    
    except Exception as e:
        print('File already protected:')
        print('Skipping this file:\n')
        return False  # Return False to indicate an error occurred

    total_excel_protected = total_excel_protected + 1
    return True  # Return True to indicate success
    

def password_protect_excels_in_folder(folder_path, password):
    global no_of_excel_file
    global total_excel_protected
    
    excel_files = [filename for filename in os.listdir(folder_path) if filename.lower().endswith(('.xlsx', '.xlsm', '.xls'))]
    
    if len(excel_files) == 0:
        print(f"The folder does not contain any EXCEL files : ", folder_path)
    
    if (enableEncryptionInNestedFolders in choiceList[0]):
        for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
            if os.path.isdir(file_path):
                # It's a sub-folder
                password_protect_excels_in_folder(file_path, password)
            else:
                # It's a file
                file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
                if filename.lower().endswith(('.xlsx', '.xlsm', '.xls')):
                    no_of_excel_file = no_of_excel_file + 1
                    success = password_protect_excel(file_path, password, filename)
    
        print("==============================")
        print("NO. OF EXCEL FILE : ", no_of_excel_file)
        print("TOTAL EXCEL FILE PROTECTED : ", total_excel_protected)
        print("==============================\n")
    
    elif (enableEncryptionInNestedFolders in choiceList[1]):
        for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
            if filename.lower().endswith(('.xlsx', '.xlsm', '.xls')):
                no_of_excel_file = no_of_excel_file + 1
                success = password_protect_excel(file_path, password, filename)
        
        print("==============================")
        print("NO. OF EXCEL FILE : ", no_of_excel_file)
        print("TOTAL EXCEL FILE PROTECTED : ", total_excel_protected)
        print("==============================\n")
```

Please clarify me if this module is compatible with the excel 97-2003 (.xls) version for getting it password protected.

I was trying to get excel 97-2003 (.xls) version password protected using the python code. However, it is not supporting for this version. Kindly guide me on this issue.